# Setting an image to the page background in an angular js based app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am a newbie to AngularJS. I developed a simple currency converter app for which I would like to set a nice image background. This is my UI code:

```
<head>

<title></title>
</head>
<body >
<center>
    <div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/050/156/original/9-stylish-vector-world-map-vector.jpg)'}">
        <div class="label" ng-controller="countryMapper" style="display:inline-block">

         //Internal code here


        </div>
    </div>
</center>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/main.js"></script>
```

I am just not able to set a full background image to the app. Please tell me how to do this *in detail*

1) If fetching the image from a URL

2) If using a local image, saved in the project

Comment: you got it sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your code tries to call a controller without first calling a specified module! After defining a module and including it in the source code, the background image displays exactly as it's meant to:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
<!-- ngApp needs to be here to use any controllers attached to the module! -->

  <div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/050/156/original/9-stylish-vector-world-map-vector.jpg)'}">
    <div class="label" ng-controller="countryMapper" style="display:inline-block">
```

[Check out the Plunker here!](http://plnkr.co/edit/1tzmrmvL8U4YgewVMk5g)

Also, just as an aside, make sure your app is *tall* enough to show the image in the first place; keep in mind that the first bit of the image is just white, so you wouldn't be able to see that it was there at all [if the div was only a few lines long!](http://plnkr.co/edit/3YkXz4uetM2mLAjrE2ME)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  $scope variable bind the image url using the following directive,

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller("countryMapper", function ($scope) {    
 $scope.url="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/050/156/original/9-stylish-vector-world-map-vector.jpg";
    });
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('backgroundImage', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + attrs.backgroundImage + ')',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        });
    };
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/00qynn1w/3/)**

Comment: @SoulRayder check the demo

Comment: I tried copy pasting same code into my project, but its not showing the image

Comment: can i get team viewer?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have that installed currently.